# EDS and Object Dictionary

Tags: canopen

What are the [EDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen#Object_dictionary) and [OD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen#Object_dictionary)? How are they created and used?

How it is that the OD comes in between the application and the [CAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controller_area_network) interface?

Answer (score 4):

At first you should read a little bit about [CANopen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen) to get familiar with the concepts. Check [www.canopen.de](http://www.canopen.de/) where you can download some specifications for free.

EDS is an abbreviation for Electronic Data Sheet. This is a text file in a specified format that contains all information about a CANopen device (a list of all supported ojects). You can edit it with a plain text editor or some commercial tools.

A CANopen-Master, that reads the EDS of a CANopen device, is able to access to the object dictionary of the device. The OD is an internal representation of all the data and functions that the CANopen device provides on the CAN bus.

The creation and usage of the obect dictionary depends on the CANopen stack you are using. It is somwhere between the CANopen stack and your application.